# I am getting compilation error in creating Oracle Proceedure

Tags: oracle

iam creating a proceedure  it is giving compilation error
of right paranthesis missing

> Line # = 9 Column # = 21 Error Text = PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right
>   parenthesis

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user1.trns (XMLDATA XMLTYPE) 
IS
BEGIN

        UPDATE table1 SET T$fld1 = 1, T$dat1 = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY') 
        WHERE  table1.T$docn IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT docn 
                FROM XMLTABLE  
                    ('/DataSet/Document/DocumentRow'
                        PASSING XMLDATA COLUMNS  
                        docn PATH '@DOCN' 
                    )  
            );

        COMMIT;

END  trns;
/
```

what am i doing wrong here

Comment: Unrelated, but: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')` can be simplified to `trunc(sysdate)` no need to convert a date to a varchar just to convert it back to a date

Comment: thanks i did changed it but still iam getting the same error

Comment: When you're using a very old version of Oracle (e.g. 9i), please mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are **missing** **data type** here as below please provide data type **for XMLTABLE column**:
here i have written **varchar2(30)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user1.trns (XMLDATA XMLTYPE) 
IS
BEGIN

        UPDATE table1 SET T$fld1 = 1, T$dat1 = TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY') 
        WHERE  table1.T$docn IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT docn 
                FROM XMLTABLE  
                    ('/DataSet/Document/DocumentRow'
                        PASSING XMLDATA COLUMNS  
                        docn varchar2(30) PATH '@DOCN' 
                    )  
            );

        COMMIT;

END  trns;
```

Here is my output
[image: Here is my output]

Comment: still i am getting the same error.  the line where it is giving the rerror is    ('/DataSet/Document/DocumentRow'

Comment: i have attached the image

Comment: I dont know which version you qare on iam using 9.2 version of oracle

Comment: i am using Oracle Database 11g  11.1.0.7.0 . can you provide you code again

Comment: after making changes  `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user1.trns (XMLDATA XMLTYPE) 
IS
BEGIN
    
       
         UPDATE table1 SET T$fld1 = 1, T$dat1 = trunc(sysdate) 
        WHERE  table1.T$docn IN
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT docn 
                FROM XMLTABLE  
                    ('/DataSet/Document/DocumentRow'
                        PASSING XMLDATA COLUMNS  
                        docn varchar2(100)  PATH   '@DOCN' 
                    )  
            );

        COMMIT;
       
END  trns;
/ `

Comment: @reader as your version is very old i think my code will not work as syntax changed very much in between time so please refer to this link and create code according to following link :  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb03usg.htm

Comment: I don't think XMLTABLE was even introduced until Oracle 10.